# How to programmatically edit PDF document in .NET application?

Tags: .net, pdf, acrobat, adobe-reader

What is the best way for a `.NET` application to programmatically edit a `.PDF` document?

Is there a solution that doesn't require `Adobe Acrobat` or `Reader` to be installed on the target machine?

Comment: Is your question right? Did you mean to say a .PDF instead of a .NET application?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a component such as ABCPDF that will allow creation and manipulation of PDF files.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think you can just edit away on a pdf. You can however exctract the content of the PDF and replace / edit that content. With the new content you can create a new PDF. ItextSharp is a free tool for that.

You will need a third party library to do that. E.g. ItextSharp. ExpertPDF.

Comment: Evenso, if you extract the content as text, you lose the styles. You'd have to manipulate the content streams at the lowest level and that's not something that can be done by somebody who doesn't speak PDF fluently. Read the intro of http://manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf

Comment: True, but it's the only free option. The comment of ChrisBint is better I think. But I'm a cheap basterd.. I never heard of ABCPDF. I should take a look at it sometimes.

Comment: My point is that, regardless of the tool you use, you can't ignore the fact that PDF is *not* a word processing format. People asking how to *edit* a PDF are asking the wrong question.